# Can we creat input stream objects other that std::cin in C++ ? Especially when the library-created one is not valid anymore due to eofbit or failbit

Tags: c++

I'm a really anxious person that I can't move on in learning new subject unless I completely understand the current one, and when I'm stuck at some object I would keep looking for resources for ages trying to sort it out even with very trivial ones.

I'm learning C++. I finished the basics, and now I'm moving on to the intermediate level; In the I/O libraries there is a big drawback that I can't understand. When the std::cin object is not valid to get new input due to EOFBIT or FAILBIT as in :

```
***    #include <iosteam>
    int main()
    {
        int ival;  // declaring an integer 
        std::cin >> ival;  // defining ival from the std input
        std::cin >> ival;  // redefining ival ...
    }***
```

If we hit a char type for the first input, the stream becomes invalid and we won't be able to use the std::cin again in any further point in the program.

Are there any solution to re-validate stream again?? , if there is not, Can we create input stream objects other than std::cin?

Comment: You mean the [`std::istream::clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) member ? Note the example in the link provided is pretty much show *exactly* how one may desire to skip over a potentially erroneous line of input data.

Comment: be more anxious: read the manual ;)

Answer (score 0):

[`std::cin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) is a global instance of type [`std::istream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream). You can create other instances of `std::istream` if you like. However, to clear the error flags you can call [`clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) inherited from `std::basic_ios`.

Comment: Hello sir. Thank you for your answer. However, the problem is that I tried to clear the error flags tons of times without any significant effect. The program keeps invalidating the std::cin object throughout the rest of the program. 
I tried to assign to a variable the iostate before it's invalid then assign it back when Invalid, but using the cin seemed not to work again. 

auto oldState = std::cin.rdstate();
std::cin >> anyvar;  //give invalid input
std::cin.setstate(oldState);
std::cin >>anyvar;  // never work again (the program terminates.)

Comment: How can I associate the console to the newly created istream object? so  I can give the input from the console window.